# Error activating Bon Toolkit for Wordpress and get the following error:

Tags: php, wordpress

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `bon_toolkit_set_options()` in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\bon-toolkit\bon-toolkit.php
>   on line 410

When I go to line 410 I see this:

```
    return $options = bon_toolkit_set_options();
    }
```

I am new to programming, very very much a FNG. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: any updates? have you solved your issue?

Answer (score -2):

Look at [the following fix](https://github.com/alexszilagyi/bon-toolkit/blob/0970e216e6fe2c96c82b0bbbac3a9e5fe6d678b5/bon-toolkit.php) in bon-toolkit source code